# Add Mounted Server to Ubuntu File Manager Side Panel

Tags: shell, ubuntu, mount, file-manager

At work I have to connect to our server every day. After becoming annoyed with having to use the GUI Connect to Server every day, I wrote a quick script (using `mount`) that does the same thing.

When I use Connect to Server, however, a link to the mounted server appears in the side panel of the File Manager, which I use all the time. How do I add this link from a terminal/shell script?

(Or even better, where can I find the code for the Connect to Server program?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use gvfs-mount rather than mount

See the discussion here: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/08/access-gvfs-mounts-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Based off of the article you provided a link to, this sounds like what I'm looking for. I'm having trouble finding any information about gvfs or gvfs-mount, though. Can anyone provide a link or further explanation on either of these?